# what should be the dimensions of image for imageButton in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, photoshop

This is the image button

[image: this is the button image]

image does not shown up as background of imageButton

this is screenshot of imageButton after putting it's background as image shown

[image: this is screenshot of imageButton after putting it's background as image shown]

Here is complete content.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.meggabyte.comppec.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEwY6.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code instead:**

```
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:src="@drawable/admin"
        android:cropToPadding="false" android:background="null"/>
```

Comment: still image is not showing up, instead there is a white color rectangular box showing in the middle of image. i think it's probably due to wrong dimensions of initial image imported into drawables folder. what should be the dimension of that image??

Comment: can you edit your question and update it with the whole xml code in that file?? and also post a screenshot of the whole screen. cause this part should be working. I tried it and its working so its something else.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign an image to your ImageView... You need a line in your XML that says

```
android:src="@drawable/some_image"
```

The background and source are different